# Pagination with AspNetCore.OData - missing @odata properties in response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, odata, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement pagination with asp.net core 2.2 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.1.0  with following configuration:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc(b =>
        {
            b.EnableDependencyInjection();
        });
    }
}
```

For this I have a testing controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)]
    public IQueryable<int> Get()
    {
        return new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

When invoking an endpoint, I would expect a response like:

```
{  
  "@odata.context":...,
  "value":[1,2,3,4,5],
  "@odata.nextLink":...  
}
```

but instead I get only:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

So how do I get those extra @odata properties?

Comment: Have you tried to derive your controller from `ODataController`?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov it didn't help, but I found solution finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to do it.

First it doesn't work with primitive types so I had to create strong one with Id property:

```
public class Value
{
    public Value(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Second I had to drop `ApiController` and `Route` attributes from controller .

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)]
    public IQueryable<Value> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Value(i)).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

And finally register odata endpoint:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Value>("Values");
app.UseOData("odata", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Comment: Holy wow, I was encountering this same issue and couldn't figure out for the life of me what was going on.  Thanks so much for sharing this!  I might open a ticket on the project on github and talk about how ambiguous the setup is...Such that it can result in this!

Comment: Jan Muncinsky: I'm wondering if you have tried this pattern with Core 3.1 and ODataCore 7.4? I am facing the same issue and have been struggling to find the right group of settings to resolve it. The lack of documentation/examples from the OData team is a continuing problem.

Comment: I'll provide a little more detail on my experience dealing with the same issue. Core 3.1 and OData Core 7.5.1. Jan seems to be correct: it doesn't work with primitive types, but it also doesn't seem to work when only returning `IQueryable` result either. Instead, the return type should be `IQueryable<T>`.